# Does wireshark support piggybacked gtpv2 messages?

Tags: wireshark

The question is simple, please see title.
I have looked everywhere and still can not find the answer.

(I can see the **P-Bit** (piggyback-bit) is set in *Packet Bytes frame*, 
Wireshark does **not** show that this bit is set in the *Packet Details frame* and it does **not** decode the piggybacked message)

I am using Version 1.3.0-FD7-SVN-322, must mention that it is not easy for me to install the latest version and try it out due to company policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for the piggyback flag was introduced with Wireshark version 1.5.0, see https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=5033.

And there were some very recent bugfixes on this topic I could not resolve a bugzilla entry for.

```
bash-3.2$ svn log epan/dissectors/packet-gtpv2.c 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r41029 | etxrab | 2012-02-14 21:23:02 +0100 (Tue, 14 Feb 2012) | 2 lines

From David Wei:
Fix handling of piggybacked messages.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r41019 | etxrab | 2012-02-13 23:22:29 +0100 (Mon, 13 Feb 2012) | 1 line

Handle piggybacked messages.
```

Maybe you should ask your admin for a more recent version of Wireshark or - better - compile it right from its svn repo. The code I've checked out is newer than the current development release (1.7.0).

If you export and post your packet in pcap format here, I can test it for you with an actual Wireshark version.

Comment: thanks, I tried later version of wireshark and it is indeed working.